# kubectl attach: Unable to use a TTY - container es-node did not allocate one

Tags: containers, kubernetes, tty

I am trying to attach to a running container in Kubernetes, however I get the error message below.

```
>kubectl attach -it es-client-2756725635-4rk43 -c es-node
Unable to use a TTY - container es-node did not allocate one
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
```

How do I enable a TTY in my container yaml?

Comment: Tried the following command:

    kubectl attach wildfly-rc-uc79a -it

And got the error:

    Unable to use a TTY - container wildfly-rc-pod did not allocate one
    If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

Comment: Try without the `-t` flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61733197/658497

Answer (score 31):

In order to have proper TTY and stdin when doing attach:

```
kubectl attach -it POD -c CONTAINER
```

The container must be configured with `tty: true` and `stdin: true`.
By default both of those values are `false`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#debugging

Example Pod:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: web:latest
        tty: true
        stdin: true
```

Comment: Note that this is for an old version of k8s v1.5 - it probably changed since then, but I don't have the time to check.

Comment: can't believe it solved my issue with k8s run on v1.26 "tty: true" thanks.

Answer (score 17):

The reason why it's failiing is because you're not passing the bash argument. This causes a failure when trying to create a tty connection.

Please try:

```
kubectl exec -it [POD-NAME] -c [CONTAINER-NAME] bash
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This successfully launches an interactive shell inside the running container which is VERY useful (thank you) but it doesn't answer the OP question of using attach.  Also please note some containers only have sh (not bash)

Answer (score 7):

For Windows, MINGW64 (git bash) does not seem to work, but PowerShell does!

```sh
kubectl exec -it abc-deployment-5d64659ff8-8tnnb -- /bin/bash
root@abc-deployment-5d64659ff8-8tnnb:/#
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I did, it didn't work, `tty` command would always return `not a tty` response and exit non-0, i.e. nothing that require `tty` would work on my terminal.

I'm making an ephemeral workstation with persistent disk as my `$HOME` with `Ubuntu Bionic Beaver` on `GKE`.

Since I had `brew` installed in my `PD` mounted `$HOME` and `brew` was in my `$PATH`, following worked for me:

```
brew install tmux
tmux new -d -s <some arbitrary session name here> ### i.e.> tmux new -d -s tty
tmux ls # Lists your sessions
tmux a  # Attach to first available session
```

Then inside tmux:
`$ tty`
Voila
`/dev/pts/0`

My agnoster is b0rkz but now I can do stuff that prompts for interactive password entry, i.e. `gcloud auth`.
[image: tmux with pts on kubectl]
[image: auth prompt]

PS: For those curious, I mounted `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group`, `/etc/passwd` into `/etc` with `configmap`

Answer (score 0):

you can add a shell container ,like this.
then you can use

```
kubectl attach -it nginx -c shell
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  shareProcessNamespace: true
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
  - name: shell
    image: busybox
    stdin: true
    tty: true
```