# kubectl cp fails with "tar: this does not look like a tar archive" on nodes running nvidia-docker

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to copy a local Python file to a running container on Kubernetes and it fails:

```
$ kubectl cp /path/to/file.py namespace/pod:/path/in/container/file.py
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
command terminated with exit code 2
```

I know the `tar` binary must be available in the container, and it is.

Does anyone know what's going on here and how I can solve this?

**UPDATE:**

After some more testing I can confirm that this only happens on nodes that run `nvidia-docker` rather than the normal `docker`. When piping things into `kubectl exec` on these nodes the stream is always empty.

So the following command yields an empty file in the pod running on a GPU-enabled node while the file is non-empty on other nodes without GPU support:

```
cat nonempty_file.txt | kubectl exec -i pod -- tee /home/jovyan/empty_file.txt
```

This has been tested using the exact same image/container on both nodes.

Comment: can you try with this I solved mine error with go program https://stackoverflow.com/a/55901093/3053228

Comment: The fact this is working on one node and not the other node sounds very very fishy. Can you double check that the container is indeed the same when you run copy on each and update your question showing this?

Comment: Also, watch out for the version spread between your `kubectl` binary and the server, since [the version difference is actually constrained](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubectl)

Comment: I actually updated `kubectl` while trying to fix this issue. The minor version of the client was 14 before and it gave me the same error.

Comment: could you try this one:  `cat /path/to/file.py | kubectl exec -it pod -- tee path/in/container/file.py 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Hanx that command fails with "Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file"

Comment: 1. If you are using some official image please provide more infomration about the image. 2. You can use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-a-configmap) and apply your script into the POD. 3. You can use [volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) and do the same. 4. You can add your file in docker file during build stage.

Comment: Turns out it actually works on one node and not the other - using the same image. The difference is that the node it isn't working on is running nvidia-docker, which I suspect is the culprit here. I've updated the original question accordingly.

Comment: I can't test it but could you please try as workaround and use configmap or volumes instead for this specific task as described above?

Comment: Is there any update on this? I can't think of a reason why kubectl cp would break for nvidia-docker containers. Thanks for the effort you've all put into debugging this so far. I'm on 1.14.9 client and EKS 1.14.9+.

Comment: UPDATE: `kubectl cp` into pod does not seem to work at all with the `AL2_x86_64_GPU` AMI type. Works fine with `AL2_x86_64`. This issue is probably also related to https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1091

Comment: Issue persists, so I've reported it to AWS as well: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/453. Interestingly Azure doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by updating  EKS AMI version.

Please install new release: [eks-ami-releases](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/releases).

See: [eks-ami-kubectl](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/453).

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look for the docs:

- [Supported releases and component skew](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/release/versioning.md#supported-releases-and-component-skew),

  > Nodes may lag masters components by up to two minor versions but should be at a version no newer than the master; **a client should be skewed no more than one minor version from the master**, but may lead the master by up to one minor version. For example, a v1.3 master should work with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 nodes, and should work with v1.2, v1.3, and v1.4 clients.
- other [github issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57748),
- [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubectl),

> kubectl is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of kube-apiserver.

- [v1.16.0 release](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/#other-notable-changes-3)

  > kubectl cp no longer supports copying symbolic links from containers; to support this use case,
  >   see kubectl cp --help for examples using tar directly
  >   opy files and directories to and from containers.

`Examples:
  # !!!Important Note!!!
  # Requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container
  # image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'kubectl cp' will fail.`

Please try and install appropriate `kubectl` version.

Hope this help

Comment: As noted in the comments to the original question this issue is not due to the version difference. I had the matching version of `kubectl` installed when I first experienced the issue and subsequently updated `kubectl` in an attempt to fix my problem.

Comment: Did you try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886146/kubectl-attach-unable-to-use-a-tty-container-es-node-did-not-allocate-one)