# kubectl exec into pod resulting in Unable to use a TTY error every time if run through automation

Tags: shell, jenkins, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

i have a simple automation to exec into a kubernetes pod but it always results in the below error :-

```shell
kubectl exec -it my-pod -c my-contaner -n my-namespace /bin/bash
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
```

I am trying to run a simple shell script using jenkins to exec into a pod and execute ls -las in the root directory but its not allowing to exec into the pod automatically. The same thing works fine if i do manually on the linux server terminal.
Can someone help fix this issue

Comment: If this is automation, you probably don't want the `-it`

Comment: Thanks coderanger but then how do i execute commands from within the pod since the login never happens as it seems or looks like even if it does then there is no session there. all i am looking for is to exec into the pod and do bla bla bla once logged in there

Comment: If this is a script, you would presumably be running something like `kubectl exec my-pod -c my-contaner -n my-namespace -- /bin/bash /myscript.sh`

Comment: ah i am simply running kubectl exec -it my-pod -c my-contaner -n my-namespace /bin/bash && ls -las and that never establishes a shell session with the pod/container

Comment: I mean that works interactively but you can't do that from a script. You would need to actually automate whatever it is you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using the below approach :-

```html
kubectl exec -ti my-pod -c my-container -n my-namespace -- ls
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same error while creating a pod during ***Jenkins*** build:

```
$ oc run netshoot-pod --attach=true --restart=Never --rm -i --tty --image nicolaka/netshoot -- curl $IP

Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file 
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter. 
Error attaching, falling back to logs
```

**Removing** `--tty` / `-t` flag has fixed it.