# Kubernetes can't get bash prompt when exec into pod

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes to exec into a pod like this:

```sh
kubectl exec myPod  bash -i
```

which works fine, except I don't get a prompt. So then I do:

```sh
export PS1="myPrompt "
```

Which I would expect to give me a prompt, but doesn't. Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: You need to use the `-i` and `-t` options to request a tty and connect stdin (`kubectl exec -it ...`)

Comment: Adding the full command: `kubectl exec -it myPod bash`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002583/kubectl-exec-into-pod-resulting-in-unable-to-use-a-tty-error-every-time-if-run-t

Comment: Thanks! I don't see where to flag that I accept this answer, but it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to exec into pod in interactive way requires specifying `-ti` option.

Where `-i` passes stdin to the container and `-t` connects your terminal to this stdin.

Take a look at the following example:

```
kubectl exec -it myPod -- bash
```